# iPhone-Resizing View and Subviews as Well

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, view, subviews

I have an app where I have two views nested inside a larger view. The smaller one is at the bottom and functions almost as a toolbar. The top/larger view contains many buttons. I have a minimize button in the top right corner that minimizes the smaller view view and should expand the top view  to make it full screen. I can minimize the small view perfectly, but I cannot expand the top view. The issue I believe is that when I minimize the small view, all I am doing is moving it down with an animation. However, the expanding is more difficult because I am actually increasing the size of the view. The issue is that the buttons won't expand wight he view and fit the full screen. Basically, the small view minimizes and the top view does nothing. How can I get the contents of the larger view to enlarge with the view itself while retaining my nice animation? Here is my code for minimizing and enlarging the respective views where the largeView contains buttons and needs to be enlarged and the miniView gets minimized. Here is the code:

```
[largeView setHidden:NO];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.3f];
[largeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 1024,900)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[miniView setHidden:NO];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.3f];
[miniView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 850, 1024, 127)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Are these view made in a xib or storyboard with auto layout turned on? You really shouldn't be using beginAnimations/commitAnimations, Apple has recommended against using them since iOS 4.

Comment: @rdelmar I used story board. I just added a view (with a size of 1024,624), made an outlet for it, and am trying to get it to become fullscreen and automatically resize its subviews. Autolayout and autoresize subviews are both turned on in interface builder. Any other suggestions on a better way to either fix this or redo this?

Comment: Yes, you should not ever set frames when you're using auto layout. You should adjust the constraints instead. Also, learn to use the newer block-based animation methods of UIView.

Comment: @rdelmar How should I go about adjusting the constraints?